# How to combine multiple columns to single columns (by header name)?

Tags: r, multiple-columns, reshape2

I currently have an Excel document that looks like this in a simplified way:

```
   A1   A2   B1   B2    B3   C1   C2   ...   H12
   1    5    11   14    15   19   22   ...   ...
   2    6    12         16   20   23
   3    7    13         17   21   24
   4    8               18        25
        9                         26
        10                        27
```

And I have to combine the columns in two different ways for two different resulting documents.
First of all, I have to combine the columns in a way that all the columns containing only the number 1 are combined, which would result in a document like this:

```
   Column 1   Column 2   Column 3   ...   Column 12 
   1          5          15         ...   ...
   2          6          16
   3          7          17
   4          8          18
   11         9
   12         10
   13         14
   19         22
   20         23
   21         24
              25
              26
              27
```

And for the second way, I would need the columns to be combined in a way that all the original columns starting with the same number are mereged into one column, such as:

```
   Column A   Column B   Column C   ...   Column H
   1          11         19         ...   ...
   2          12         20
   3          13         21
   4          14         22
   5          15         23
   6          16         24
   7          17         25
   8          18         26
   9                     27
   10
```

The headers of the file to transform are numbered from A1 up to H12. This means that the first resulting document should have 12 columns in the end and the second document 8 columns.

I have already tried to do so with `rbind`, but I didn't manage to do so.

Could anybody please help me with this problem?

Thank you very much already in advance!

Comment: Is your question about how to reshape the data, how to read and save Excel files, or both?

Comment: The question is about how to reshape the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitely more elegant ways, but without knowing how your header or your data looks like in reality, this would be a relatively magic-free path:

(Disregarding the Excel part of the post, which would probably be more suited in a separate question, if it's a question at all)

## Data

```r
> df <- structure(list(A1=c(1L,2L,3L,4L,NA,NA),A2=5:10,B1=c(11L,12L,13L,NA,NA,NA),B2=c(14L,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),B3=c(15L,16L,17L,18L,NA,NA),C1=c(19L,20L,21L,NA,NA,NA),C2=22:27,H12=c(28:30,NA,NA,NA)),row.names=c(NA,-6L),class=c("data.frame"))
```

## Code

#### Put data into long form

```r
library(tidyverse)
# Put data.frame into long format
df_long <- df %>%
    # Put data into long format
    gather(key, val) %>%  #you could also use pivot_longer()
    drop_na() %>%
    # Separate letters and numbers
    separate_wider_regex(cols = key, patterns = c(letter = "[^0-9]+", number = "[0-9]+")) %>%
    # Sort
    arrange(letter, number) 

# Result
> head(df_long)
  letter number val
1      A      1   1
2      A      1   2
3      A      1   3
4      A      1   4
5      A      2   5
6      A      2   6
...
```

#### Generate letters table

```r
# By letters
df_letters <- df_long %>%
    # Drop number col
    select(-number) %>%
    # Add rolling ID
    group_by(letter) %>%
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    # Spread into wide format
    pivot_wider(
        id_cols = id, names_from = letter, names_prefix = "Column_", values_from = val
    ) %>%
    select(-id)

# Result

> df_letters
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   Column_A Column_B Column_C Column_H
      <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
 1        1       11       19       28
 2        2       12       20       29
 3        3       13       21       30
 4        4       14       22       NA
 5        5       15       23       NA
 6        6       16       24       NA
 7        7       17       25       NA
 8        8       18       26       NA
 9        9       NA       27       NA
10       10       NA       NA       NA
```

#### Generate numbers table

```r
# By numbers
df_numbers <- df_long %>%
    # Drop letter col
    select(-letter) %>%
    # Add rolling ID
    group_by(number) %>%
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    # Spread into wide format
    pivot_wider(
        id_cols = id, names_from = number, names_prefix = "Column_", values_from = val
    ) %>%
    # Drop ID col
    select(-id)

# Result
> df_numbers
# A tibble: 13 × 4
   Column_1 Column_2 Column_3 Column_12
      <int>    <int>    <int>     <int>
 1        1        5       15        28
 2        2        6       16        29
 3        3        7       17        30
 4        4        8       18        NA
 5       11        9       NA        NA
 6       12       10       NA        NA
 7       13       14       NA        NA
 8       19       22       NA        NA
 9       20       23       NA        NA
10       21       24       NA        NA
11       NA       25       NA        NA
12       NA       26       NA        NA
13       NA       27       NA        NA
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works very well! But in the resulting file, there are three columns missing, namely column 10, 11, and 12. Could you please help me solving this problem? Thanks a lot already in advance!

Comment: @Hotshot Good point, thanks. I exchanged `separate` for `separate_wider_regex` to work robustly with columns in the form of **[non-numbers][numbers]**

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have no problem with reading the Excel, so I will assume you just read in the whole worksheet to the data.frame `table`. You can use `tidyr::pivot_longer` to get a data frame, where there is a reference to the row title in one entry and the value in the other:

```
table <- pivot_longer(table, cols = names(table), values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

Then you can create two additional columns with the number and the letter with `substring`:

```
table$number <- substring(table$name, 2)
table$letter <- substring(table$name, 1, 1)
```

The writing can be done in two for loops: (I use `openxlsx`)

```
byNumbers <- buildWorkbook("")
for(i in 1:12){
  vec <- c(i, filter(table, number == i)$value)
  writeData(wb = byNumbers, sheet = 1, x = vec, startCol = i)
}

byLetter <- buildWorkbook("")
for(i in 1:8){ # H is the 8th letter
  iLet <- LETTERS[i]
  vec <- c(iLet, filter(table, letter == iLet)$value)
  writeData(wb = byLetter, sheet = 1, x = vec, startCol = i)
}
```

You can then save the two Workbooks.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So far, it seemed to work quite well. But there are no data frames generated. How could I then save the new workbooks?

Comment: With openxlsx you just use `saveWorkbook(byLetter, file = path1)` ore the same with the byNumbers workbook and another path